# Where's the Java API documentation for Google Documents List API 3.0?

Tags: google-docs-api

Since Google Documents List API Version 3.0, there is now no separate Java guide as there was for v2.0 (now deprecated).

There are sprinklings of Java but mostly there is .Net. 
I'm having to refer to the deprecated API (v2.0) to get meaningful documentation for Java.

Just wondering if the Java doc is going to be updated at some point to be as complete as .Net
and do you recommend we keep using the deprecated API doco in the meantime.

I thought Google was a Python / Java house so why the .Net bias ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should adopt the newer Google Drive API, which has all the features of the Documents List API and complete Java documentation:

https://developers.google.com/drive/

Comment: Except, it doesn't have batch upload support yet, which for a lot of people is a deal breaker atm.

Comment: @AlexHart Exactly.  DocsList has been deprecated for almost two years now, and its Drive successor still doesn't support batch mode.  Even if they do ever get around to killing off DocsList, it's still a currently supported API today... so it's bizarre to have documentation only for .NET rather than languages that any Google developers actually use.